# Interface type in AVRO schema

Tags: go, serialization, interface, schema, avro

How can we define the interface valued map in the AVRO schema?

What is the type we need to mention here for the interface Map?

```
map[string]interface{}{
    "key1" : []int{1,2,3,4},
    "key2" : []int{"One","Two","Three", "Four"},
    "key3" : map[string]interface{}{
        "subkey1" : 1,
        "subkey2" : "1",
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, the request is not clear to me. Can you try to better explain it? Maybe add the final JSON you're interested in. Thanks!